# Resque-scheduler loading schedules but not enqueuing them

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque, resque-scheduler

When I run

```
rake resque:scheduler RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the following output:

```
2013-09-19 18:16:16 Reloading Schedule
2013-09-19 18:16:16 Loading Schedule
2013-09-19 18:16:16 Scheduling aa_job 
2013-09-19 18:16:16 Scheduling bb_job 
2013-09-19 18:16:16 Scheduling cc_aggregator 
2013-09-19 18:16:16 Schedules Loaded
```

However I can see that none of this jobs get actually enqueued.I know my worker is up and running because if I do something like

```
Resque.enqueue(aa_job)
```

It gets enqueue and executed as expected.

Other thing, if I do `Resque.schedule` in my Rails console, I get `{} (empty)`

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

did you have workers on the corresponding queue?

`resque_scheduler` is only responsible for *enqueueing* jobs , i.e: you need to run both:

`rake resque:scheduler RAILS_ENV=production`  and   `QUEUE=* rake resque:work`

Comment: OP states that his worker *is* up and running because he can enqueue jobs and see them being executed.

Comment: how to run these both the commands in entrypoint.sh file?

rake resque:scheduler RAILS_ENV=production and  QUEUE=* rake resque:work

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. It appeared that there was another scheduler process started, and when I started one more, it wrote that it scheduled job, but actually it didn't. So I just restarted all scheduler processes and now it works fine for me.

Comment: how did you restarted all scheduler processes?

Comment: I run `ps aux|grep resque`, find there pids for each resque-scheduler process, and then killed each using `kill -9 pid` command. Then monit started new process for me, but you probably should do it manually in any convenient way.

Comment: In case anyone else is using foreman to run start the scheduler and the workers, you'll find that stopping foreman necessitates doing what RaskolnikOFF suggests

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which was solved by loading `environment` in the scheduler rake task:

```
rake environment resque:scheduler RAILS_ENV=production
```